# Divergence theorem, Gauss's theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, divergence-operator

$$\mathbf F(x,y,z)=x\mathbf i + y\mathbf j+z\mathbf k$$ and
$$ D=\left\{x,y,z\in \mathbf R^3 : 0\le z \le1-x^2-y^2\right\}.$$

I want to calculate both

$$\iiint_D\nabla\cdot\mathbf F\,dV = \oint_{\delta D}\mathbf F \cdot\mathbf N\,dS.$$

So far:

$$\nabla f=1+1+1=3$$

$$\oint_{\delta D}f\cdot n\,dS=\iiint_D=3\,dV$$

and after that

$$v(D)=\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^rr^2\sin(\phi)\,dr\,d\theta \,d\phi=\frac{4\pi r^3}{3}.$$

But what is the $r$ in there? Is it $r=1$?

$$\frac{4\pi1^3}{3}=\frac{4\pi}{3}?$$

And after that:

$$\oint_D\mathbf F\cdot \mathbf N\,dS=\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}r(\theta,\phi)\cdot \mathbf n\,dS=\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}r^3\sin(\phi)\,d\theta\,d\phi=4\pi r^3,$$ and this $4\pi r^3$ should be equal to $\dfrac{4\pi}{3}$ but is it not. There must be some mistake somewhere but where?

Comment: In your integrated integral for $v(D)$, $r$ is one of the dummy variables integrated over.  So there should not be an $r$ after the integration.

Comment: Oh yes then it would be $4\pi=4\pi$

Comment: Also, it looks like you're integrating over a sphere and $D$ is not a sphere.

Comment: For $r$, you are using $r$ to be two different things. First you have it as the dummy variable of itegration representing the radial distance to the point, Second it is the upper limit of integration on the inner integral, which makes it an actual, not dummy, variable. it is the $r$ in the role of the actual variable $r$ that appears in the RH side, not the dummy variable. And the confusion here is exactly what happens *every last single time* someone foolishly uses the same symbol to mean two different things in the same context. Please take a lesson from this and do not do it again.

Comment: As  Matthew Leingang has noted, $D$ is not a sphere. It is a paraboloid. Because the $z$-axis is an axis of rotation, this would be easier to do in cylindrical coordinates, not spherical. Also note that the Divergence theorem requires integrating over the surface of $D$. Even if you hadn't been mistaken about the shape being a sphere, $D$ only has values of $z \ge 0$, but you integrated over the whole sphere.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, $D$ is not a ball.  It's bounded below by the unit disk in the $xy$-plane, and above by the paraboloid $z=1-x^2-y^2$.  (You may be thinking of $z = \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$; that surface is the upper unit hemisphere.)  In cylindrical coordinates,
$$
    D = \left\{(r,\theta,z) : 0 \leq r \leq 1,\ 0 \leq z \leq 1-r^2 \right\}
$$
So
\begin{align*}
    \iiint\limits_{D} \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}\,dV
    &= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-r^2} 3 r\,dz\,dr \,d\theta
    \\&= 3\cdot 2\pi \int_0^1 r(1-r^2) \,dr
    \\&= 3 \cdot 2\pi \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3\pi}{2}
\end{align*}

The boundary of $D$ is the union of two surfaces:
\begin{align*}
    S_1 &= \left\{(r,\theta,0) : 0 \leq r \leq 1 \right\} \\
    S_2 &= \left\{(r,\theta,1-r^2) : 0 \leq r \leq 1 \right\} \\
\end{align*}
As oriented surfaces, $\partial D = S_2 - S_1$.  On $S_1$, the normal vector is vertical, and $\mathbf{F}$ has no vertical component.  Therefore,
$$
    \iint\limits_{S_1} \mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf{N}\,dS
    = \iint\limits_{S_1} (x \mathbf{i} + y \mathbf{j}+z\mathbf{k}) \cdot \mathbf{k}\,dA
    = \iint\limits_{S_1} 0\,dA = 0
$$
On top, $S_2$ is the graph of $z=1-x^2-y^2$, so the vector $\left<2x,2y,1\right>$ is normal to $S_2$.  Therefore
\begin{align*}
    \iint\limits_{S_2} \mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf{N}\,dS
    &= \iint\limits_{S_1}\left<x,y,1-x^2-y^2\right>\cdot\left<2x,2y,1\right>\,dA
    \\&= \iint\limits_{S_1}(1+x^2+y^2)\,dA = \iint\limits_{S_1}(1+r^2)\,dA
    \\&= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 (1+r^2)r\,dr\,d\theta
    \\&= 2\pi \int_0^1 \left(r + r^3\right)\,dr = 2\pi \cdot\frac{3}{4} = \frac{3\pi}{2}
\end{align*}
Therefore
$$
    \iint\limits_{\partial D} \mathbf{F}\cdot \mathbf{N}\,dS = \frac{3\pi}{2}
$$